# CentOS 8 won't boot after kernel and nvidia drivers updated

Tags: centos, kernel, boot, nvidia

After I updated kernel and installed nvidia drivers via official repository, system won't boot and all I see is an infinite aer message loop:

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: AER: aer_status: 0x00000001, aer_mask: 0x00000000
snd_hda_intel 0000:41:00.1: AER: aer_layer_physical Layer, aer_agent=Receiver ID
nvidia 0000:41:00.0: AER: aer_status: 0x00000001, aer_mask: 0x00000000
nvidia 0000:41.00.0: AER: aer_layer=Physical Layer, aer_agent=Receiver ID
```